# Set margin property for an element nested in a floated div

Tags: html, css-float

Why margins do not work inside this floated element?

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bph8D/3/).

```
    <div id = "floated">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>

#floated
{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
}
#content
{
   margin: 30 30 30 30;
}
```

Comment: If you mean 30 pixels, it should be `30px`.

Comment: `margin: 30px` http://jsfiddle.net/Bph8D/4/

Answer (score 3):

As BoltClock said it's 30px not just "30": http://jsfiddle.net/Bph8D/3/

```
#floated {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
}
#content {
    margin: 30px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should type "px". change #content to:

```
 margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
```

or briefly:

```
margin: 30px;
```